# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' on Spyder

Tags: python, selenium, spyder

I have written a code that works perfectly on my personal computer(on Pycharm). When I ran the code on another system(on Spyder) I am getting error as below. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I have very limited access to this computer. How can I install Selenium to avoid the error?

```
  File "C:/Users/pchou/.spyder-py3/Test_Code1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I tried to install it through pip and pip3 but it gives me error as below

```
C:\Users\pchou\.spyder-py3>pip
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\pchou\.spyder-py3>pip3
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image: Code for importing Selenium Webdriver]

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed pip.

You can get installation help for pip here [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)